# Process.ProcessName returns w3wp instead real name

Tags: c#, iis

I have web api hosted on IIS, I need to get its name.
The code I tried:

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
process.ProcessName;
```

That gives me just w3wp where I am expecting to be dll name or the name of the project in solution.
how to get more accurate name  ?

Comment: The name of the process is usually the name of the exe, not any dll or project/sln name.

Comment: Why not use a  Global Constant? The process is (usually)  the exe executing the app (in this case the IIS)

Comment: *"hosted on IIS"* - What you're getting **is** the name of the process.  What exact information are you looking for?  A specific assembly name?

Comment: The actual process you're running in is probably the web server or the like. If what you want is the name of the current assembly then you're not interested in any process. Call `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` and then get the name from there.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the process is the name of the exe running it.

If you want the name of the dll of the current assembly, you can use [`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=netframework-4.6) to access the current assembly meta-data.

For example for the name you can use:

```
string name = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Comment: it gives me mscorlib

Answer (score 1):

In a web application hosted in IIS, you can use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly) to retrieve information about the main assembly in your web application project.